# Find all div with id (not class) inside <article> beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

In my personal scraping project I cannot locate any job cards on https://unjobs.org neither with requests / requests_html, nor selenium. Job titles are the only fields that I can print in console. Company names and deadlines seem to be located in iframes, but there is no src, somehow href also are not scrapeable. I am not sure whether that site is SPA. Plus DevTools shows no XHR of interest. Please advise what selector/script tag contains all the data?

Comment: Here's an archived version of the site in question: https://web.archive.org/web/20201022185813/https://www.comparis.ch/gesundheit/arzt/pathologie

Comment: Thank you for rapid reply! I mistakenly thought that Web Archive changes html.

Comment: Nope, they just add their header on top.

Comment: still need help ? @Vogel

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη I am afraid, yes. Checked the webarchive but my site doesn't have any json with data. In Network panel I also can't see any internal apis with json. Should I post new question?

Comment: @Vogel you can [edit] your current question and post all details.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη edited

Comment: @Vogel below you should have an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with `CloudFlare` firewall. You've to inject the cookies. I couldn't share such answer for injecting the cookies as CloudFlare bots is very clever to fetch such threads and then improving the security.

Anyway below is a solution using `Selenium`

```py
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

mainurl = "https://unjobs.org/"


def main(driver):
    driver.get(mainurl)
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
                (By.XPATH, "//article/div[@id]"))
        )
        data = (
            (
                x.find_element_by_class_name('jtitle').text,
                x.find_element_by_class_name('jtitle').get_attribute("href"),
                x.find_element_by_tag_name('br').text,
                x.find_element_by_css_selector('.upd.timeago').text,
                x.find_element_by_tag_name('span').text
            )
            for x in element
        )
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        print(df)

    except TimeoutException:
        exit('Unable to locate element')
    finally:
        driver.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    data = main(driver)
```

> Note: you can use `headless` browser as well.

Output:

```
                                                    0                                           1 2                   3                                        4
0   Republication : Une consultance internationale...  https://unjobs.org/vacancies/1627733212329     about 9 hours ago     Closing date: Friday, 13 August 2021
1   Project Management Support Associate (Informat...  https://unjobs.org/vacancies/1627734534127     about 9 hours ago    Closing date: Tuesday, 17 August 2021
2        Finance Assistant - Retainer, Nairobi, Kenya  https://unjobs.org/vacancies/1627734537201    about 10 hours ago   Closing date: Saturday, 14 August 2021
3                  Procurement Officer, Sana'a, Yemen  https://unjobs.org/vacancies/1627734545575    about 10 hours ago   Closing date: Wednesday, 4 August 2021
4   ICT Specialist (Geospatial Information Systems...  https://unjobs.org/vacancies/1627734547681    about 10 hours ago   Closing date: Saturday, 14 August 2021
5   Programme Management - Senior Assistant (Grant...  https://unjobs.org/vacancies/1627734550335    about 10 hours ago    Closing date: Thursday, 5 August 2021
6   Especialista en Normas Internacionales de Cont...  https://unjobs.org/vacancies/1627734552666    about 10 hours ago   Closing date: Saturday, 14 August 2021
7         Administration Assistant, Juba, South Sudan  https://unjobs.org/vacancies/1627734561330    about 10 hours ago  Closing date: Wednesday, 11 August 2021
8   Project Management Support - Senior Assistant,...  https://unjobs.org/vacancies/1627734570991    about 10 hours ago   Closing date: Saturday, 14 August 2021
9   Administration Senior Assistant [Administrativ...  https://unjobs.org/vacancies/1627734572868    about 10 hours ago  Closing date: Wednesday, 11 August 2021
10  Project Management Support Officer, Juba, Sout...  https://unjobs.org/vacancies/1627734574639    about 10 hours ago  Closing date: Wednesday, 11 August 2021
11  Information Management Senior Associate, Bamak...  https://unjobs.org/vacancies/1627734576597    about 10 hours ago    Closing date: Saturday, 7 August 2021
12  Regional Health & Safety Specialists (French a...  https://unjobs.org/vacancies/1627734578207    about 10 hours ago      Closing date: Friday, 6 August 2021
13  Project Management Support - Associate, Bonn, ...  https://unjobs.org/vacancies/1627734587268    about 10 hours ago    Closing date: Tuesday, 10 August 2021
14            Associate Education Officer, Goré, Chad  https://unjobs.org/vacancies/1627247597092             a day ago     Closing date: Tuesday, 3 August 2021
15  Senior Program Officer, High Impact Africa 2 D...  https://unjobs.org/vacancies/1627597499846             a day ago   Closing date: Thursday, 12 August 2021
16                   Specialist, Supply Chain, Geneva  https://unjobs.org/vacancies/1627597509615             a day ago   Closing date: Thursday, 12 August 2021
17  Project Manager, Procurement and Supply Manage...  https://unjobs.org/vacancies/1627597494487             a day ago   Closing date: Thursday, 12 August 2021
18  WCO Drug Programme: Analyst for AIRCOP Project...  https://unjobs.org/vacancies/1627594132743             a day ago    Closing date: Tuesday, 31 August 2021
19                    Regional Desk Assistant, Geneva  https://unjobs.org/vacancies/1627594929351             a day ago   Closing date: Thursday, 26 August 2021
20                        Programme Associate, Zambia  https://unjobs.org/vacancies/1627586510917             a day ago  Closing date: Wednesday, 11 August 2021
21  Associate Programme Management Officer, Entebb...  https://unjobs.org/vacancies/1627512175261             a day ago   Closing date: Saturday, 14 August 2021
22  Expert in Transport Facilitation and Connectiv...  https://unjobs.org/vacancies/1627594978539             a day ago     Closing date: Sunday, 15 August 2021
23  Content Developer for COP Trainings (two posit...  https://unjobs.org/vacancies/1627594862178             a day ago
24        Consultant (e) en appui aux Secteurs, Haiti  https://unjobs.org/vacancies/1627585454029             a day ago      Closing date: Sunday, 8 August 2021
```

Comment: Running this code I receive: "selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (os error 10061)"

Comment: And how you find out that it was issue with Cloudflare? In my tries I used either headers or random fake user agent and in errors there was no mention about blocking, only different NoType messages. While normal browsing the website I also didn't encounter any Cloudflare captchas. Have you tried to make auto-screenshot with python or what?

Comment: Is it line in viewsource <script async src='/cdn-cgi/bm/cv/669835187/api.js'></script></head> that indicates CloudFlare presence?

Comment: @Vogel make a simple request to the site! what's the response code ? you will get `403`, then check `response.headers['Server']`

Comment: Above code worked after changing Firefox webdriver to Chrome. Any ideas what is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like either Cloudflare knows your request is not coming from an actual browser and is giving a captcha instead of the actual site and/or you need javascript for the site to run.

I would try using something like puppeteer and see if the response you get is valid.